# At a sequence point all previous accesses to volatile objects have stabilized

Tags: c, gcc, language-lawyer, volatile, sequence-points

From GNU [document](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Volatiles.html) about `volatile`:

> The minimum requirement is that at a sequence point all previous
>   accesses to volatile objects have stabilized and no subsequent
>   accesses have occurred

Ok, so we know what [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point)s are, and we now know how volatile behaves with respect to them in gcc.

So, naively I would look at the following program:

```
volatile int x = 0;
int y = 0;

x = 1;    /* sequence point at the end of the assignment */
y = 1;    /* sequence point at the end of the assignment */
x = 2;    /* sequence point at the end of the assignment */
```

And will apply the GNU requirement the following way:

At a sequence point (end of `y=1`) access to volatile `x = 1` stabilize and no subsequence access `x = 2` have occurred.

But that just wrong because non-volatiles `y = 1` can be reordered across sequence points, for example `y = 1` can actually be performed before `x = 1` and `x = 2`, and furthermore it can be optimised away (without violating the as-if rule).

So I am very eager to know how can I apply the GNU requirement properly, is there a problem with my understanding? is the requirement written in a wrong way?

Maybe should the requirement be written as something like:

> The minimum
>   requirement is that at a sequence point **WHICH HAS A SIDE EFFECT** all previous accesses to volatile objects have stabilized
>   and no subsequent accesses have occurre

Or as pmg elegantly suggested in the comment:

> The minimum requirement is that at a sequence point all **UNSEQUENCED** previous accesses to volatile objects have
>   stabilized and no subsequent accesses have occurred

so we could **only** apply it on the sequence points of end of `x = 1;` and end of `x = 2;` on which is definitely true that previous accesses to volatile objects have stabilized and no subsequent accesses have occurred?

Comment: `x=1;/*access to x stabilized*/y=1;/*no worries about x, even with optimization or reordering*/`

Comment: means that requirement should be changed to something like `The minimum requirement is that at a sequence point AT THE END OF THE VOLATILE EXPRESSION all previous accesses to volatile objects have stabilized and no subsequent accesses have occurred` ?

Comment: there is no need to distinguish sequence point types. If you want to change the paragraph, try "... at a sequence point all *unsequenced* previous accesses ..."

Comment: so you agree the current paragraph is wrongly wirrten?

Comment: I think the paragraph is ok as it is in gnu documentation :)

Comment: Do you understand the purpose of `volatile` in C/C++?

Comment: @curiousguy I believe I do. The question here is about a specific requirement which I feel to be written wrongly.

Comment: @user2162550 `volatile` makes something observable. The abstract machine, by definition, isn't observable. Ergo the question about non volatile writes doesn't make sense: the as if rules says that nothing in the abstract machine needs to be translated sequence point by sequence point.